# How to automatically set the thread instead of user having to set it in django

Tags: django

I am trying to create a discussion forum website with django. Everything is working, but I want to change one thing and I have no idea how to.

In the website users can create threads and posts inside those threads. When a thread is created there is a button in that thread that says add a post in this thread. Then it will take them to a form. Right now, if the form were to work they would have to select from a dropdown menu which thread they wanted to add a post to. I want the thread to be the thread that the button they clicked was inside of.

models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('thread-view', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-view', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py:

```
def homeView(request):
    context = {
        'threads': Thread.objects.all().order_by('-created_at'),
        'posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    }

    return render(request, 'forum/home.html', context)

class ThreadCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Thread
    fields = ['title', 'description'] 
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content'] # Right now I also have to add in 'thread' as a field but I don't want that to be the case


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
path('', homeView, name='forum-home'),
path('create-thread/', ThreadCreateView.as_view(), name='create-thread'),
path('create-post/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create-post'),
```

home.html:

```
{% for thread in threads %}
    <div class="border-bottom pb-2">
        <h2><a href="{% url 'thread-view' thread.pk %}">{{ thread.title }}</a></h2>
        <p>{{ thread.description }}</p>
        <p>{{ thread.created_at|naturaltime }}</p>
        <p>{{ thread.user }}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add a post to this thread</a>
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% if post.thread == thread %}
                <div class="border p-2 m-3">
                    <h3><a href="{% url 'post-view' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
                    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                    <p>{{ thread.created_at|naturaltime }}</p>
                    <p>{{ thread.user }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>       
{% endfor %}
```

post_form.html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Post</legend>
        {{ form }}
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Any tips would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you facing issue ?

Comment: @Println I am facing an issue of coming up with a way so that it automatically sets the value of thread to be the thread button that they clicked

Comment: You can add the primary key of the thread in your `create-post` url, so `create-post/<int:thread_pk>` and then use that pk when you create the post to assign the thread. But you need more changes in your template to use this thread pk in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not having a separate view / url for the creation of a Post and simply write a dedicated detail view and template for single Threads. In the template add your form for submitting posts. You can create a custom Post ModelForm that accepts the input and validates it.

This might be easier to do with a function-based view, but you'll have to check for `request.method == POST` then manually save the instance. If anyone has a cleaner class-based view solution I'm all ears.

```
# forms.py

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for processing post submissions.
    """
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['content']
```

```
# views.py

from .forms import PostForm

def topic_posts(request, *args, **kwargs):

    # Put queries and logic for listing posts here

    # Get thread from url params
    thread = Thread.objects.get(id=kwargs['thread_id'])
    redirect_uri = # build redirect back to thread

    # Custom model form
    pform = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    # Save post instance on POST request
    if request.method == 'POST' and pform.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
        pinstance = pform.save(commit=False)
        pinstance.author = request.user
        pinstance.thread = thread
        pinstance.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_uri)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After a bit of tweaking this solution works beatifully.